# Asp Website hosting with database in App_Data Folder

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, web, web-hosting

I have windows hosting server with SQL Server / Mysql database and I want to host a website with database, when developing the website I create SQL Server database ie `.mdf` database inside the `App_data` folder and it works fine in my system

My question is whether this website will work correctly when I publish this to a windows hosting server [ I don't want upload database separately] ,

If it is not - please tell me is this OK with SQL Server CE or Sqlite database

Somebody please help me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your local system,it would work since you have IIS and SQL Server both in same system and you have attached .MDF locally. If you deploy your website to shared hosting environment, most web hosting providers do not host Web server (IIS ) and SQL Server in same host. Additionally, in order to run database locally, your web hosting provider must have SQL compact in Web server.

> My question is whether this website will work correctly when I publish
>   this to a windows hosting server [ I don't want upload database
>   separately]

It is recommended to host website in web server, host database in SQL server and write appropriate connection string in web.config for the database connectivity.